# How to have 2 domain names pointing to same website, one http and the other https

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, httpd

I currently have rewrite working on `example.com`, the entire site is HTTPS, using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I need a lot of files on this exact same website, accessible via a second domain name, and over HTTP, for example: `http://example.net/files/....`

I tried adding `example.net` as a `ServerAlias`
 but of course this just redirect and then rewrites to `https://example.net/files`

I copied the rewrite rule from the internet, and am unsure of the correct way to modify it.

I was thinking along the lines of changing rewrite rule to something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^example.com/?(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

so that URLs are only rewritten if they include `example.com` 
Then would I need a rewrite rule for the TLD domain itself and not this wildcard entry?

Please can somebody help with the correct way to achieve this, so that requests to the `ServerAlias` (`example.net`) are not rewritten?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to point two domains to the same content. eg. `example.com` and `example.net`. Then create separate virtual hosts for each domain but point them to **same document root**. Add one VirtualHost entry with 80 for HTTP (`http://example.com`) and another domain entry with 443 with HTTPS (`https://example.net`) and assign require SSL entries.

Comment: Yes. Except I think you got the domains the wrong way round... you'd need 3 virtual hosts: `example.com:80` (that simply redirects to 443), `example.com:443` and `example.net:80`.

Answer (score 0):

As Sunil suggests, you can create separate virtual hosts and the SSL redirect would then only occur in the first one (ie. `example.com` port 80). (You can also avoid mod_rewrite and just use a single mod_alias `Redirect`, which would be preferable.)

However, you can also do what you were suggesting and create a `ServerAlias` for `example.net` (your *other* domain) and include a *condition* (ie. `REwriteCond` directive) in your current redirect that only redirects the `example.com` domain. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Note that this should really be a 301 (permanent) redirect, once you have confirmed it's working OK. ie. `[R=301,L]`.